# php.ini default timezone vs. date.timezone

Tags: php, timezone

When I use PHP's `date()` function on two different servers, I get two different results, but both servers should be the same.

I checked the `php.ini` file on server #1, where the time is correct, and it looks as follows:

```
date/time support                   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database                   internal
Default timezone                    America/Chicago

Directive        Local Value        Master Value
---------------------------------------------------
date.timezone    America/Chicago    America/Chicago
```

I checked on server #2 and it looks as follows:

```
date/time support                   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database                   internal
Default timezone                    UTC

Directive        Local Value        Master Value
---------------------------------------------------
date.timezone    America/Chicago    America/Chicago
```

The only difference I see is the "Default timezone" value.

The date/time for both servers current display as:

```
Server #1: 10/23/2012 09:40:39
Server #2: 10/23/2012 14:40:39
```

I confirmed that both servers use the `php.ini` located within `/etc` and I also searched both web directories for any place the timezone might be overwritten:

```
grep -r "date_default_timezone_set" *
```

But in that regard, they both contain the same files with the same settings.

Is "Default timezone" what's causing the 5h difference? If so, how do I correct it?

**UPDATE**

*Loaded configuration files.*

Server #2 contains two additional ini files:

```
/etc/php.d/snmp.ini
/etc/php.d/apc.ini
```

*php -i results.*

Server #1:

```
date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/Chicago

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.timezone => America/Chicago => America/Chicago
```

Server #2:

```
date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/Chicago

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.timezone => America/Chicago => America/Chicago
```

What's interesting to note here is that for some reason the "Default timezone" does not match on server #2 when viewing it via `php -i` versus `phpinfo()` on a web page.

**SOLUTION**

The problem was with the CMS and its plugins. While server #1 and #2 had the same files and everything, it appears that plugins are not loaded in the same order on each server, which allowed the last plugin loaded to determine the timezone of my script.

The reason `php -i` and `phpinfo` differed is because after you use `date_default_timezone_set()`, it affects what `phpinfo()` will print.

The fix was the ensure that I'm in the timezone I needed to be in via `date_default_timezone_set()`. The reason that didn't work for me before I posted this question was because I declared this prior to loading a few required files from the CMS, which probably set the timezone again in there.

Comment: Is the system time on both servers the same?

Comment: it really is a good idea to configure all your servers to use UCT as their base date. It makes everything so much more predictable.

Comment: @AlexLunix Yes, I just checked and they are both the same: `Tue Oct 23 10:03:57 CDT 2012`

Comment: @SDC Yes, I agree. At this point, I'm just trying to get them to be the same. If I can do that, I can set them to UTC.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I found out that Laravel configurations overwrites php.ini default timezone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) relies on the [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) INI setting. Since one is Chicago (CT) and the other is UTC, that is your 5 hour difference.

*I believe* as of PHP > 5.2 you should receive:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function.

I would encourage you to look at the new [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object or use UTC as advised by **SDC**.

Comment: `date.timezone` is set inside php.ini. And they are both set to the same value on both servers. I'm not sure where the "Default timezone" is set.

Comment: +1 for recommending the DateTime class. It doesn't get itself as badly into a mess over timezones than the old date handling functions. And it's far more functional too. The `date()` function and its friends should be thrown into the pit and never brought back.

Comment: It's not set somewhere, hence the `Default timezone UTC` on Server #2.

Comment: Where do I go set that? Or where do I go on server #1 to unset that?

Comment: Are you sure the INI's are the same? Run the following on both servers: `php -i | grep timezone`

Comment: Server #1:
`Default timezone => America/Chicago
date.timezone => America/Chicago => America/Chicago`

Server #2:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
Default timezone => America/Chicago
date.timezone => America/Chicago => America/Chicago`

I see the warning. Could that have anything to do with that?

Comment: What's interesting to note is that when using `php -i` on server #2, the "Default timezone" is listed as `America/Chicago` but in `phpinfo()` it's listed as `UTC`.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible that your command line PHP and your web server's PHP are different?

Comment: Anything is possible. I inherited those servers, so I'm not sure how it was setup and configured. What would be a way to find that out?

Comment: Compare `phpinfo()` against `php -i`. Specifically versions and loaded INI. See the post by **bradym** too.

Comment: Between `php -i` and `phpinfo()`, the loaded configuration file matches on both server #1 and #2. The build date is off by 5 minutes, but they match in the `php -i` for both server #1 and #2. The PHP API version and following values are the same. But for some reason, under DATE, in `php -i` on server #1 "Default timezone" matches (`America/Chicago`), but on server #2, `php -i` reports `America/Chicago`, but `phpinfo()` reports `UTC`.

Answer (score 5):

A few things to check:

1. Check the "Loaded Configuration File" value in your phpinfo() output to make sure you're changing the correct php.ini file. (This has bitten me more than once!)
2. When looking at phpinfo() output check the "Additional .ini files parsed" line to see if there are additional ini files being parsed when running via your web server.
3. date.timezone can be set via the ini_set function. Do you have any code that does that? Be sure to check any code that may be running due to the auto_prepend ini setting as well.

Comment: [1.] Just double checked again, and yes, they both are loaded from `/etc/php.ini` [2.] I noticed that on server #2, there are two additional ini files: `snmp.ini` and `apc.ini`. [3.] Would I search for something like `init_set(date.timezone`?

Comment: [2] Those ini files shouldn't have anything for date.timezone, but I'd check anyways. [3] Close, look for ini_set function calls - http://php.net/ini_set

Comment: [2.] I've looked into both files and there's nothing about time in them. [3.] I performed a search on both servers and the only `ini_set` functions I saw are related to error display.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code:

```
[Date]
date.timezone = ('America/New_York')

date.default_latitude = 31.7667

date.default_longitude = 35.2333

date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

Just change `date.timezone = ('America/New_York')` to your desired timezone.

[Source](http://www.gizmozine.com/2013/12/date-timezone-zen-cart-fix.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

The TZ environment takes precedence over the php.ini default value; maybe that's the reason why. You can fix this, by explicitly calling date_default_timezone_set.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 14.0 LTS
Default timezone in my case was set in:

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

I could then verify with:

php -i | grep "timezone"

Comment: For the command line interface (cli) yes. But the apache web php settings are in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

If you set the date.timezone value in php.ini but it does not work (ie. local value and master value are different) then you might need to update something like this in your apache configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value date.timezone "Europe/Paris"
</IfModule>
```

To the mod who deleted the above answer before: I have searched hours to find this solution. Don't delete an answer just because you think it is a duplicate answer.