# PHP - output of date('now') is a ahead of local time by 6 hours, but time zone is set to correct local zone zone?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timezone, gmt

I'm in St. Louis, MO in the USA Central Time Zone. We are -6 GMT

The PHP time zone setting in php.ini is date.timezone = "America/Chicago"

(Chicago is almost directly north of St. Louis.

echo date('now'); produces: December 19, 2015, 2:45 am. EDIT - I meant date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime("now"));, not date('now');

Locally (by calendar and clock) it is December 18, 2015, 8:45 pm.

Here is the date information as output by phpinfo()

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2015.1
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    America/Chicago

Directive               Local Value     Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667         31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333         35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith     90.583333       90.583333
date.sunset_zenith      90.583333       90.583333
date.timezone           America/Chicago America/Chicago
```

I thought that if the correct time zone is set, date('now') would return the local time and time - but I'm obliviously wrong.

What am I missing about the date() function or PHP date handling in general?

SimonT

Comment: What's the output of the `date` UNIX command on your server?

Comment: Don't understand your question. How do it get that output, what do I enter and where? It is not my server, it is the hosting companies - is the date command something that would be entered at the console?

Comment: Are you sure your PHP environment is pointed at the *correct* PHP.ini file?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6433721/634824).  If that doesn't help, try following [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033491/634824).

Comment: The information I showed in my question is from phpinfo(). That should be the one used, shouldn't it? I added date_default_timezone_set ("America/Chicago"); to my code and now I get the correct date. Why would phpinfo() be showing the same value and not taking effect?  I don't have the access needed to do what was said on the accepted answer to question you referred to me. To see output of phpinfo - http://thetesting.site/phpinfo.php "Loaded configuration file" shows the one on my hosting account. Any other things I should check? I would really rather not have to set the timezone in all code.

Comment: Ok - found it, but am unsure how to proceed. Added phpinfo() to the function where I was having the date problem - it shows "Default timezone  UTC" That page is part of a wordpress blog. On the stand alone page that shows the output of phpinfo(), default timezone shows as America/Chicago. All the other info in the Date section of phpinfo() is the same - only default timezone is different. date.timezone shows as America/Chicago in both phpinfo() - standalone and on wp page. I thought date.timezone would be used by date functions. Short of setting it in code, how do I override the "UTC"?

Comment: More -- how is that being overridden? I would understand if the WP modules set the zone but how is the ini field overridden? Also, posts and comments on the blog are dated correctly - WP has a setting for the difference between local and UTC and it is set correctly. So, where is that "default timezone UTC" coming from and how can I get around it - or do I have to set the time zone in all my scripts on the WP blog?  But, more I think about it, makes less sense given that WP is using correct dates but in my code there gets the wrong date???? My code is called by WP code.

Comment: One last thing - to clarify - phpinfo() shows "default timezone UTC"  If I set it the timezone and then do another call to phpinfo() default timezone is what I set it to. If this is a problem which which ini file is "first" why would setting timezone in code cause phpinfo() output to change? When you set the timezone, does it change the ini file? I would think not, I'd expect it to simple set the zone for the duration of the script - right? For the time being I'll set the zone in my code and hope that I remember to do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can choose to handle this:

- You can use `date_default_timezone_set` to override Wordpress's time zone setting.
- You can use the [PHP `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of the `date` function, which accepts a time zone in the constructor
- You can change Wordpress's time zone setting in the WP Admin / Settings / General section:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: WP's timezone is already set to Chicago, has been since installation.. That was among the first things I checked.   Post and comment dates have always shown correct dates. As I said in comments to  Matt Johnson, I'll resort to setting the timezone in all scripts - I've put in the theme's function.php. I want to find out how WP is overriding the zone setting in my php.ini file - see my comments, above, to  Matt Johnson

Comment: Yes, that's me (same Matt Johnson).   Until your comments, it was unclear your question was about WordPress at all.  I'm no WordPress expert, but scanning the source, it appears WordPress calls `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` in several places, which is probably why you don't see the effect of your php.ini timezone setting.   The setting in their admin screen appears to be applied on a case-by-case basis, rather than globally.  You might consider doing that as well.

Comment: Matt, Sorry for the name confusion l I need to pay more attention.I find WP to be a bloated attempt to be everything for everyone and still be something that the average person can customize - it does not succeed. I've been in data processing for over 4 decades and I can truthfully say that I have never encountered a software package - system or application - as poorly done as this - the code is horrendous, the documentation is poorly designed and written.- It is just a mess - and the community venerates the guy who started the package. Thanks for your help. I'll try to grin and bear it..

Comment: You pretty much summed up how I feel about PHP in general.  Give me C# any day.  Heck, give me Java, Python, or Ruby even.

Comment: If I have to chose - give me IBM Assembler (as in what are now called mainframes) I consider it my second spoken language. You have absolute control and don't have to worry about what a compiler or interpreter is going to do to your code. One thing I HATE about PC languages is case sensitivity - it's nuts! There is no defensible reason for having a case sensitive language - none.